# JqueryUI and bootstrap interference with dialog display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm having problems getting jqueryUI and bootstrap to work together.

Example here
https://jsfiddle.net/2hcwxudd/1/

My Code:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Welcome">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>

$(function () {
$("#dialog").dialog({
    show: {
        effect: "fold",
            duration: 500
        },

    });
});
```

You can see on the dialog show there is a small resize event at the end of the animation that looks horrible. I can't seem to figure out what's causing it or how to resolve it, but removing bootstrap resolves the problem.

I've tried noConflict (it's not the js its the css thats causing it), and i've tried using various themes which all seem to have the same problem.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can we have your css code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to `box-sizing` in bootstraping, you have to `unset` `box-sizing` property like,

```
.ui-dialog,.ui-dialog *{
    box-sizing:unset !important;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/2hcwxudd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem with the width of dialog box,

the hack is define `min-width`,

```
.ui-dialog {
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hcwxudd/2/)

Comment: Perfect, this fixed it. Thanks so much!